# How would I make a reload command in Python for a discord bot?

Tags: python, discord, bots, discord.py

I am trying to figure out how to make a command that 'reloads' a Discord Bot's commands and allows me to keep the bot running while I am adding new commands.

This just makes life easier for me so I don't have to reboot the bot.

I'm using the discord.py library to interact with the discord API.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 7):

Probably late to this questions, but I will post it anyways

You should checkout how so called "Cogs" work in Discord.py. [The bot from Rapptz](https://github.com/Rapptz/RoboDanny) (the guy who main-maintain Discord.py) has some good examples how to organize your bot into Cogs and how to load/unload/reload them (see `cogs/admin.py` for that).

```
@commands.command(hidden=True)
@checks.is_owner()
async def load(self, *, module : str):
    """Loads a module."""
    try:
        self.bot.load_extension(module)
    except Exception as e:
        await self.bot.say('\N{PISTOL}')
        await self.bot.say('{}: {}'.format(type(e).__name__, e))
    else:
        await self.bot.say('\N{OK HAND SIGN}')

@commands.command(hidden=True)
@checks.is_owner()
async def unload(self, *, module : str):
    """Unloads a module."""
    try:
        self.bot.unload_extension(module)
    except Exception as e:
        await self.bot.say('\N{PISTOL}')
        await self.bot.say('{}: {}'.format(type(e).__name__, e))
    else:
        await self.bot.say('\N{OK HAND SIGN}')

@commands.command(name='reload', hidden=True)
@checks.is_owner()
async def _reload(self, *, module : str):
    """Reloads a module."""
    try:
        self.bot.unload_extension(module)
        self.bot.load_extension(module)
    except Exception as e:
        await self.bot.say('\N{PISTOL}')
        await self.bot.say('{}: {}'.format(type(e).__name__, e))
    else:
        await self.bot.say('\N{OK HAND SIGN}')
```

([Snippet from `cogs/admin.py`](https://github.com/Rapptz/RoboDanny/blob/master/cogs/admin.py#L18))

Comment: since when are exceptions handled in the command itself and not its error handler?

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the basic reload built into discord.py

Here is an example of how my `reload` command is done.

```
@bot.command()
@commands.is_owner()
async def reload(ctx, extension):
    bot.reload_extension(f"cogs.{extension}")
    embed = discord.Embed(title='Reload', description=f'{extension} successfully reloaded', color=0xff00c8)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Sends an embeded message when the cog is reload but you can always just do `ctx.send(f'{extension} reloaded)`